# How to pass a dataTable from C# code behind to jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have string to pass as a table of data from C# code behind to jQuery.
for that I am using two functions:

**C#**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static List<ListItem> GetImageArray(string AccNo)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var obj = new AccountTransaction();

    DataTable dt = obj._commonobj.SearchAccNo(AccNo, "", "GETIMAGE");
    List<ListItem> datas = new List<ListItem>();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string CustImg = Convert.ToString(row["Customer Image"]);
            string SignImg = Convert.ToString(row["Sign"]);

            ListItem listitem = new ListItem(CustImg, SignImg);
            datas.Add(listitem);                  
        }
    }
    return datas;
}
```

**Client-side**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AccountTransaction.aspx/GetImageArray",
    data: "{'AccNo':'" + col1 + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnImgSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});

function OnImgSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
    });
}
```

`return datas;` returns 2 row and  `alert(response.d)` is not showing anythig
[image]

I tried using `$.map(data, function (listitem)` function but no result .

```
 $.map(data, function (listitem) {
    $('<tr> <td>' + listitem.CustImg + '</td> <td>' + listitem.SignImg + ' </td> </tr>').appendTo(".tblData");
 });
```

Please help .!

Comment: you are very close to solution. inspect the object you get from controller in developer console and you will find it.

Comment: @Doruk C# function looks ok ,because i have 2 row values on the variale `datas`  but am not getting those values on success function..

Comment: offtopic: 'data' is plural, there's no such word as 'datas'  (you could use 'dataList')

Comment: Never use `alert` on an object - you just get `[object Object]`.  Use `console.log(response)` and look in the console.  The fact that you get two [object] in your alert shows that it's returning an array/list just fine.

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried using `console.log(response)` , its not showing anything.! leave the alert can you please tell me how to take first value from list.. Am using `listitem.CustImg` but i thing its not the right way

Comment: What does the network tab says about your ajax query ?

Comment: Check my answer @Four and tell me if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is there in the `d` property, so you can use the `map` function but using the `data.d` instead of just `data`.

Then the `ListItem` properties are `Text` and `Value`, so your code should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AccountTransaction.aspx/GetImageArray",
    data: "{'AccNo':'" + col1 + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: onImgSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});

function onImgSuccess(data) {
    $.map(data.d, function (listitem) {
        $('<tr> <td>' + listitem.Text + '</td> <td>' + listitem.Value + ' </td> </tr>').appendTo(".tblData");
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code.

```
alert($.parseJSON(response.d));
```